# How to register OData extension methods in .NetCore 3.1 outside of UseMvc middleware

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

After migrating my API from .net core 2.2 to 3.1, I am facing some issues to decide which is the best approach I should follow to register OData extension methods for my API. Currently, I have this code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
          ....
             #region OData

            services.AddOData();

            #endregion  
          ....
 }
```

On the Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
 {
  ...
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
                        {
                            routeBuilder.Select().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(1000).Count();
                            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
                        });
   ...
 }
```

How can I register Select() OrderBy() Filter() .... using the following approach? Is this the right way to do it, without registering UseMvc?

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
 {
        ...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article out: [Experimenting with OData in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/).

Apparently .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1 don't support OData yet. You can, however, use the [beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.3.0-beta) version, the steps for which is explained in the article.

**Update:**

They do support OData as of version 7.3.0. However, they cannot be used with endpoint routing yet. You can follow [this Github thread](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748) for updates, in particular, this [answer](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748#issuecomment-568245644)

Comment: they support OData, I posted a question there https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/#comment-129